# Time format for Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

[image]

how can i show only time in Crystal report my requirement is time format "hh:mm tt" but how it possible give me an idea working in vb.net crystal report

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the field >> Format Object >> Under Date and Time Tab >> Select the required Fromat and you can click on customize to re-format>> Under Date and Time Tab select from Order Mneu to show only Time >> and Under Time Tab select your Format 24 or 12 and to show hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: when click on Format Object then display only this tab "Common","Border","Front","Paragraph" and "Hyperlink" not mention the "Under Date and Time" tab

Comment: @QaziAhmad If you're seeing the "Paragraph" tab then your field is a string, not a datetime. Is this a database field, formula, or something else?

Comment: brother Ryan you are right saying but brother field data type is datetime in sql database how can i do this.

Comment: If the field is a datetime in the database but it's not a datetime on the report canvas you need to investigate what the field on the canvas is (formula, etc.) and possibly replace it with the database field.

Comment: btrother can you tell me formula

Comment: You can use Siva`s approach then format it as i mentioned previously

Answer (score 2):

you can use `CTime` function to get the time value:

```
CTime(TimeIN)
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic729.html%23id_2006123114004d2762e2_746

Comment: tell me with some explanation

Comment: Its a time function for that input should be your datetime database field... if input is datetime then output will be only time... check the edit

Comment: Brother Siva thank you for helping your method is prefect and i do this

Comment: @QaziAhmad No Problem.. I would be happy if my answer helps you